# Just get list of merge happened on my current branch in git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-log, git-reflog

Is there any way in Git you can just list all Branch merge commmits?
I tried with `git reflog` and it does show commit and

```
<commit number> HEAD@{2}: commit (merge): merge with feature/unification
```

Is using (merge) string enough to detect branch merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
git log --merges
```

> ### `--merges`
>
> Print only merge commits. This is exactly the same as
>   `--min-parents=2`.